# How to tell if shrimp is already cooked and what to do with it?

Tags: shrimp

I have some shrimp. Not sure if this is raw, and what to do with it to make it safe for eating. I'm not looking for a recipe, but a method of preparing these shrimp. I know how to peel shrimp, am I to boil them? Fry them? Do they look raw to you? Can I eat raw shrimp? If not, do I boil them? Thanks!

[image: Shrimp, what to do?]

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30156/are-cooked-frozen-shrimp-safe?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the label, you see "**CKD** SHRIMP..." which I read as "cooked shrimp".

Even without the label, you have two indicators for cooked:

- the **colour**: raw shrimp are greyish-green, they turn pink when cooked
- the **body shape**: raw shrimp have a more "stretched" body, they curl up during cooking.

Comment: Wow! Thank you :) this helped. Would it be okay to eat if I peeled, and rinsed it? (Or should I boil the peeled shrimp a bit, too?) How was this shrimp cooked? Can you tell by looking?

Comment: Are they frozen? Then thaw (gently, not in a microwave), rinse, peel. Then either just eat or use as ingredient in a dish. These were either boiled or steamed. As far as boiling them again is concerned, I'd be very careful, lest they get rubbery.